# How to return date from date time?

Tags: date, datetime, formula, openoffice-calc

I have OpenOffice Calc column with the following entries:

```
10/21/12 09:39 AM
12/20/12 05:35 AM
04/30/13 12:47 PM
```

How do I extract the date part so that output is?:

```
10/21/12 
12/20/12 
04/30/13
```

Comment: is there anything unclear with my answer? Did you manage to solve your issue?

Answer (score 2):

Just apply **[`ROUNDDOWN()`](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_ROUNDDOWN_function)** or **[`INT()`](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_INT_function)** to the date value to strip the time information; you may have to apply date formatting manually.

The date value `10/21/12 09:39 AM` is internally stored as `41203.4020833333` by Calc. [Calc uses integers for dates and fractions for time values](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_Date_%26_Time_functions). So, the date part of `10/21/12 09:39 AM` is `41203`. Rounding down the value `41203.4020833333` to `41203` effectively strips the time information, leaving just the date (to be precise: the result is `10/21/12 00:00 AM` - so it's just a matter of formatting the cell as date or date/time.